# java : cannot convert from String to int

Tags: java

```
public class NewRoot {
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        int number = arguments[0];
        System.out.println("The square root of"
                + number
                + " is "
                + Math.sqrt(number)
            );
}
}
```

eclipse shows an error saying

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int
```

even though I put 225 on an argument.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: use `int number = Integer.parseInt(arguments[0])` you can't cast `String` into `int` directly.

Comment: it is because **String[]** parse the string to int as @user3218114 said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert `String` to integer,

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(arguments[0]);
```

Comment: _However, this throws a `NumberFormatException` and your program crashes._

Comment: @Unihedron Yes `NumberFormatException` will throws if your argument is not the integer one.